# Closed formula for the sum of the following series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I find the closed formula for the sum $$1/3 + 1/27 + 1/243 + ...?$$

Comment: the general term is 3^{-(2n+1)} starting at n = 0

Comment: HINT: This is a geometric series. Determine the ratio between successive terms and then use the formula for the sum of a geometric series with $n$ terms. You should find that the common ratio is less than 1 and thus you can use the sum to infinity of such a series.

Comment: Try multiplying the series by $9$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's geometric series:

$$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{27}+\frac{1}{243}+\cdots=\frac{1}{3}(1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\cdots)=\frac{1}{3} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{9^i}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{9}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$S=\frac 13+\frac 1{27} +\frac 1{243} +\dots + \frac 1{3^{2n+1}}+\dots$$

Then multiply by $9$ $$9S=3+\frac 13+\frac 1{27} +\dots + \frac 1{3^{2n-1}}+\dots=3+S$$

So that $8S=3$. If you ever forget the formula for a geometric progression, you can recovering this way (dividing or multiplying by the common ratio).

Comment: Neat observation!

Answer (score 1):

Putting $r=\frac13$, your series is

$$r^1+r^3+r^5+r^7+\cdots = (1+r^1+r^2+r^3+\cdots)-(1+r^2+r^4+r^6+\cdots)$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-r}-\frac{1}{1-r^2} =\frac{1}{1-\frac13} - \frac{1}{1-\frac19} = \frac32 - \frac98 = \boxed{\dfrac38}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the recurrence $$S_n=\frac13+\frac19S_{n-1},$$
with $S_0=0$.

We have
$$S_1=\frac13,$$
$$S_2=\frac13+\frac1{27},$$
$$S_3=\frac13+\frac1{27}+\frac1{243},$$
$$S_4=\frac13+\frac1{27}+\frac1{243}+\frac1{2187},$$
$$...$$
If it converges to some $S$, we must have
$$S=\frac13+\frac19S,$$
$$S=\frac38.$$
And it does converge because it is a sum of positive terms, bounded above by $3/8$. Indeed,
$$S_{n-1}<\frac38\implies S_n=\frac13+\frac19S_{n-1}<\frac13+\frac19\frac38=\frac38.$$

Comment: Note that there is no circular argument like "if it converges, then the limit is $3/8$; if the limit is $3/8$, then it converges". The proof is: "it is bounded by $3/8$ so that it converges; if it converges, the limit is $3/8$".