# Calculate exact value of and infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, infinity

Im trying to find the exact value of the infinite sum :

**3 + 1/3 + 1/27 + 1/243 + 1/2187 + ...**

I can see that to generate new terms we take the previous term and divide by 9 or multiply by 9. Not exactly sure if one way or the other makes it any easier. This is what i have come up with to solve the series is this correct and where do i go from here?

$\sum_{k=3}^\infty= K_0 + K_n(1/9)\\ $

Comment: Should there be a term $1/243$ included?  If not, it is not clear what the series is.

Comment: Yes, my apologies

Comment: Your very description is the definition of a geometric series. Do you know how to sum a geometric series?

Comment: @agha:  It is the same question except with the $3$ added in front.

Comment: $3/3^0 + 3/3^2 + 3/3^4 + 3/3^6 + 3/3^8...$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the idea presented by @MarkBennet in [Closed formula for the sum of the following series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934215/closed-formula-for-the-sum-of-the-following-series) we first let:$$S=3+1/3+1/27+1/243+1/2187+...$$Then divide both sides by 9 to get:$$S/9=1/3+1/27+1/243+1/2187+1/19683+...=S-3$$Therefore:$$3=S-S/9=8S/9$$$$8S/9=3$$$$S=(9*3)/8=27/8$$

**NOTE**: This method only works for a series where the magnitude of the common ratio between terms is less than 1.

Comment: This is elegant, but still needs the (easy) fact that $S$ exists -- i.e., that the series converges.

Comment: Yes - as I commented in an answer above, this generalisation can only be performed if the magnitude of the common ratio is less than 1.

Comment: where is the 8 coming from?

Comment: I've added more clarification in the answer above

Comment: Got it thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You are always dividing by $9$ in the examples given.  Do you know how to sum a geometric series?You can say that if $S$ is the sum, $S=3+S/9$, as the divide by $9$ changes each term to the next.

Comment: No, im not exactly sure how to sum the geometric series

Comment: You could look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) below "as $n$ goes to infinity..."

Answer (score 0):

By term-wise cancellation,
$$\begin{align}
S&=a+ab+ab^2+ab^3+ab^4...\\
Sb&=\ \ \ \ \ \ \ ab+ab^2+ab^3+ab^4...\\
S-Sb&=a
\end{align}$$ 
we have$$S=\frac a{1-b}.$$
This is only valid when the sum converges, which requires $|b|<1$.

Applied to the given case, we have
$$S=\frac3{1-\frac19}=\frac{27}8.$$

Comment: im still a bit unsure whats happening on the right side of your equation

Comment: There are 8 equalities in my answer. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: I believe this is only true if the magnitude of the common ratio between terms is less than 1. e.g. if $S=1+10+100+...$, then $10S=10+100+...=S-1$ which would imply $S=-1/9$ which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: Absolutely, you need $|b|<1$,otherwise the sums are infinite and the manipulation of the equations does not make sense. $b=1/9$ clearly passes this test!

Comment: $b=1/9$ does indeed pass the test - I was commenting more on your generalisation above. It might be worth adding the note that this only applies if $|b|<1$